# iPhone Database of People with Properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database

In the iPhone app I am developing, I need to have a list of people which is stored.

So the user go into the 'People' view and there I want a table view which the user can edit by adding and removing people to their list. Each person will also need to have properties, such as first name, last name, age etc as some examples.

I am unsure of how to approach this as its my first time. My main curiosities are how to have a list of people and go to a view displaying that persons unique properties. How to have each entry/person have its own unique properties (which I can define) and how to save/load them. It of course has to be persistent, so when the application is quit the data stays when reloaded.

Obviously code samples help understanding a lot, but any pointing in the right direction is really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too broad to really answer, but here's some pointers:

- Use Core Data for storage.
- Create a Person class, with each person being an NSManagedObject with various properties like first name, last name and so on.
- Use an NSFetchedResultsController to populate a TableView with your people.

Answer (score 1):

CoreData is the way to go. I have found this tutorial particularly helpful when I was learning iOS and CoreData.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

But Apple Documentation is good as well.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Answer (score 0):

Easiest: Use NSUserDefaults. Define a class "Person". Store instances of "Person" in an NSArray and save it in NSUserDefaults. It'll give you persistence but little else. If you have any search or data modification operations, you'll have to write your own code and it can become cumbersome pretty soon. For very simple apps only.

SQLite3: You'll need to know/learn about SQL a bit and also know how to design tables, but will keep your life simpler if you need to do sophisticated searches, etc.

Core Data: Apple's recommended solution to all your database needs. Highest learning curve, but simplifies many sophisticated tasks (undo operations, etc.). A good choice for 90% of the apps.